# Allow Gmail Login for only GSuite Enterprise Accounts in a Web App

Tags: gmail, google-workspace, google-admin-settings-api

There is a requirement in my web app which needs a provision to allow Google Sign-in for only those users who has G-Suite Enterprise accounts only and bypass other users.

Any link/steps/help would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Now, I tried checking App Permissions and settings with Administrator access on Google Admin account but still couldn't find an option to allow access only to Enterprise Account users.

Also, I searched Google Cloud Console and searched for any settings but couldn't find any.